# prometheus-kube-stack: How to disable node exporters & Grafana on GCP GKE - v1.21.10-gke.2000

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I can disable node exporter deployment locally in k3d, but as it seems i **can't** disable the deployment of node exporters and Grafana on my nodes (GCP GKE - v1.21.10-gke.2000.) in my GKE cluster.

I am using helm chart details below:

```
- name: kube-prometheus-stack
  version: "35.0.3"
  repository: "https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts"
```

I used following command in my values.yaml.

```
kube-prometheus-stack:
  grafana:
    enabled: false
    adminPassword: xxx
    ingress:
      enabled: false 
      ingressClassName: nginx
      hosts:
        - xxx
      tls:
        - secretName: letsencrypt-prod-monitoring-crt
          hosts:
            - xxx

  prometheus:
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      ingressClassName: nginx
      hosts:
        - xxx
      tls:
        - secretName: letsencrypt-prod-monitoring-crt
          hosts:
            - xxx

    prometheusSpec:
      scrapeInterval: 1m
      scrapeTimeout: 1m

  ## Deploy node exporter as a daemonset to all nodes
  nodeExporter:
    enabled: false

  kubeStateMetrics:
    enabled: false

  ## Configuration for prometheus-node-exporter subchart
  prometheus-node-exporter:
    prometheus:
      monitor:
        enabled: true

  # prometheusOperator:
  #   admissionWebhooks:
  #     enabled: false
```

Is there anything special about GCP GKE that plays a role in the deployment of Prometheus node exporters and Grafana?

Answer (score 0):

kube-prometheus-stack(https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) depends on prometheus-node-exporter(https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/Chart.yaml#L46)

i'd use k8s affinity to discard node-exporter pods from undesired nodes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).